# Согласование слов или построение фразы

Tags: грамматика, согласование

Как объяснить с точки зрения грамматики фразу «...крестя их во имя Отца и Сына и Святого Духа»? Нужно не значение, а строение словосочетания.

Comment: Хорошо бы уточнить вопрос. Вас сам оборот "во имя" интересует? Или фраза целиком?

Answer (score 1):

**...крестя их во имя (кого?) (Отца и Сына) и Святого Духа...**

Три однородных дополнения соединены по схеме (2 + 1):  первый союз И связывает два первых дополнения (между ними более тесная связь), а второй союз присоединяет третье дополнение.

Таким образом, здесь **нет повторяющегося союза И...И, запятые не ставятся.**

Comment: Не думаю, что церковь разделяет Вашу точку зрения. Все три Лица существуют в полном единстве, они "равночестны, единосущны и сопрестольны". Тут скорее исторические причины искать надо.

Comment: Мне не надо искать, я знаки не только по правилам, но и по интонации могу ставить. Перечислительная интонация есть? Нет.  Тогда и запятых нет. И получается: у церкви концепция, а у Лопатина правила, кто-то из них должен поправиться или как-то объясниться.

Answer (score 0):

> Итак, идите, научите все народы, *крестя их **во имя** Отца и Сына и Святого Духа*, уча их соблюдать все, что Я повелел вам...
> [Св. Евангелие от Матфея, глава 28](https://www.bibleonline.ru/bible/rus/40/28/)

[***До правки*** вопрос звучал так: "Нужно не значение, а строение словосочетания **во имя**..."]

[**во и́мя**](https://www.efremova.info/word/vo_imja.html#.W0BkpPZuLIU), ***предлог**, с род. пад.*
Употребляется при указании на кого-либо или что-либо как цель действия; **ради кого-либо, чего-либо.**
Это устойчивое (неразложимое) сочетание:
**составной** (предлог + сущ.), **производный** (из двух слов), **отыменный** (переход существительного в его состав) [**предлог**](https://unotices.com/page-answer.php?id=3105).

*Она пела о последней войне и страшном поражении, о предательстве тех, **во имя** кого мы сражались* (С. Ветров. Магия в крови).